# wordpress redirect loop on the login page (wp-login.php)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication, admin

I am working on a wordpress  site (3.0.1) everything was ok. now i can't login to my admin BO. 
I have a endless redirection !

I have tried this : 
    cleaning cookies, disable plugins...

I have added :

```
@define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
```

On wp-config.php, but nothing changes .

Can you help please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a server restriction with the firewall! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps.

Log in to wordpress database using phpmyadmin. 
go to wp_options table and go to page two. 
Remove active plugins. 
If you have a backup of the old database paste the plugins back in. OR

1) Backup your .htaccess file on your hard drive
2) Delete the .htaccess file from the root of your server
3) Go to your blog’s admin panel and log-in
4) On the left sidebar, go to Settings –> General and changes your WordPress Address and Blog Address to include www (so it should be http://www.domainname.com instead of http://domainname.com).
5) Save Settings
6)Take your .htaccess backup and reupload it to the root of your server/directory

Comment: Is it multisite wordpress?

Comment: Try this if you haven't `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.name' );` Note: do not add www.

Comment: still no changes ! same probleme .